# Hibernate join columns not by a primary key reference

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have User and Role classes with ManyToMany relationship. When I'm adding Role object to List roles in User object the 'user_roles' table columns 'username' and 'role_name' gets populated with User and Role objects primary keys' which are their ids. I wanted to know whether its possible to reference not primary keys(ids) and get username and Role.name in those columns instead?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@SecondaryTable(name = "user_info", pkJoinColumns = {
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "info_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id") })
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name = "user_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@ManyToMany 
@JoinTable(name="user_roles",
            joinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="username"/*, referencedColumnName="username"*/)},
            inverseJoinColumns= {@JoinColumn( name="role_name"/*, referencedColumnName="role_name"*/)}
)
private List<Role> roles;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

@Id
@Column(name = "role_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "role_name")
private String name;

@ManyToMany
private List<User> users;
```

Also if I remove the comments around referencedColumnName I get error when trying to fetch all users from the database. I haven't added any data to database so even when querying empty database I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references
>   to a collection: com.recipee.model.User.roles

The reason I'm using such database schema is because I'm trying to use Tomcat realm authentication where I need username and role_name in one database table.

Comment: The error message suggests that you're sharing the same list of roles in two different users. Are you doing that? If so, don't.

Comment: @JBNizet I don't think so. All I'm doing is calling listUsers() method which has query to database like so: `List<User> userList = session.createQuery("from User").list();`